# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_STYLE

Tags: java, maven, cxf

When deploying a war file at a jetty server the NoSuchFieldError occur:
at `com.xxx.ws.wscommon_v22.ClientContextType.toString(ClientContextType.java:382)`

Rebuilding the war file may fix the problem, but not always.

The offending codeline is from a apache xjc generated file:

```
@Override
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2018-02-28T10:32:27+01:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.11")
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, JAXBToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE);
}
```

In the war there is only one instance of JAXBToStringStyle, and that is from:

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
```

The other cxf libraries are version 3.2.1, except cxf-xjc-ts which is 3.1.

The error indicates that there is a conflict in versions, but I can't seem to figure out why.